# Can't view the node list in NetworkX

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I am a newbie. I am playing around with Networkx. I am having difficulty with the docs. I don’t find them very user friendly for a person with my inexperience.

I have manually created a node list and an edglist for a graph. I can successfully draw it. However I am seeing the following issues:

1. When I `print G.nodes()` I get a list of nodes but when I `print G.edges()` I get nothing.
2. List item `path = nx.shortest_path(G, source='Debra', target='John')` returns with an error

> networkx.exception.NetworkXNoPath: No path between Debra and John.

Here is my sample code:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()        
edges = [
('Freda', 'Olive', 0), ('Freda', 'John', 0), ('Freda', 'Debra', 0), ('Ollie', 'Mercedes', 0), 
('Ollie', 'Freda', 0), ('Ollie', 'Bryant', 0), ('Debra', 'Walter', 0), ('Debra', 'Levi', 0), 
('Debra', 'Jennie', 0), ('Debra', 'Robin', 0), ('Olive', 'John', 0), ('Olive', 'Ollie', 0), 
('Levi', 'Ollie', 0), ('Levi', 'John', 0), ('Levi', 'Walter', 0), ('Jennie', 'Levi', 0), 
('Jennie', 'John', 0), ('Jennie', 'Freda', 0), ('Jennie', 'Robin', 0), ('Mercedes', 'Walter', 0),
('Mercedes', 'Robin', 0), ('Mercedes', 'Bryant', 0), ('John', 'Bryant', 0), ('John', 'Debra', 0), 
('John', 'Walter', 0), ('Robin', 'Ollie', 0), ('Bryant', 'Olive', 0), ('Bryant', 'Ollie', 0), 
('Bryant', 'Freda', 0), ('Bryant', 'Mercedes', 0), ('Walter', 'John', 0), ('Walter', 'Levi', 0), 
('Walter', 'Bryant', 0)]

nodes = ['Freda', 'Ollie', 'Debra', 'Mercedes', 'Levi', 'Jennie', 'Olive', 'John', 'Robin', 'Bryant', 'Walter']

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=nodes,node_color='k',alpha=0.1)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=edges,edge_color='k',width=1, alpha=0.2)
print G.nodes()
print G.edges()    
path = nx.shortest_path(G, source='Debra', target='John')
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you're adding the edges to your NetworkX Graph. Try adding the line:

```
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

after (or instead of) adding the nodes. The reason you can see the edges when drawing is because you are passing them in explicitly to the `nx.draw_networkx_edges` function, which won't be necessary after adding them as above.

Comment: but doesn't 'nx.draw_networkx_edges' do this? I think I am confused about the concepts.

Comment: ok got it working but only after changes the edge 3-tuples to 2-tuples by removing the final parameter